# Media Queries content adaptation

Tags: css, media-queries

I cannot handle correctly my `#main-wrapper` behaviour for `@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px)`

What I am trying to get is that `#main-wrapper` has 100% width for resolution <1400px and >1400 its width is set to 1336px

Now `#menu-section` overflows `#content-section`

Live example:
http://solutionsmvo.nazwa.pl/nell-ogrody/o-nas/

Code:

```css
#main-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#menu-section {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    height:100vh;
    position: fixed;
}

#content-section {
    width: 75%;
    float:right;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    #main-wrapper {width: 1336px; margin: 0 auto;}
}
```

```html
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="menu-section">
    </div>  

    <div id="content-section">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

because your `#menu-section` in <1400px has `position: fixed;` property, it's okay in this case, but when width > 1400px, then this problem occur. remove `position: fixed;` and test it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `position:fixed` on your sidebar element.

You need to add position relative to `main-wrapper` and change position from fixed to absolute in your `menu-section`

```
#main-wrapper {
  position: relative
}
#menu-section {
  position: absolute; //instead of fixed
}
```

Comment: but I need `position: fixed;` for the `#menu-section` not to move while scrolling

Comment: Well, then consider setting the fixed width of 335px to the #menu-section, because the width won't change on Screens larger than 1400px, so it doesn't matter. And you will have your scroll effect.